# Returning pointers to interfaces but keep ownership & lifetime to the provider

Tags: c++, pointers, api-design

I have the following set of libraries

- Some interfaces
- Provider library. It will provide objects with defined interfaces.
- Consumer library. It uses objects of defined interfaces.
- Coordinator library. Uses the Provider to create objects and pass them to the consumer.

My problem is about the API design of the Provider. Let's take an example:

```
class Provider
{
    // One way is to return a reference to an owned object.
    // This is useful because no pointers are returned
    // so that no one will be asking about ownership and lifetime.
    // - The provider owns the object and
    // - The lifetime of the object is the same as the provider.
    const ObjectInterface &getObject(int id) const;
}
```

These are the semantics I want to keep.

- The provider owns the object and
- The lifetime of the object is the same as the provider.

But the previous interface will not be helpful in case a set of objects need to be returned.

```
class Provider
{
    // This is the easiest way.
    // Is this the best way?
    std::vector< ObjectInterface * > allObjects() const;

    // Using shared_ptr violates the semantics described above
    // and requires allocation on heap.

    // Using weak_ptr violates the semantics described above
    // and requires allocation on heap.

    // Using unique_ptr violates the semantics described above
    // and requires allocation on heap.
}
```

**Is there a better way for designing this API to return pointers to interfaces whose concrete objects are owned by the provider while keeping the following semantics (which is the natural semantics of returning a reference (&) to an object)?**

- **The provider owns the object and**
- **The lifetime of the object is the same as the provider.**

Comment: Use smart pointers, with the provider returning weak pointers.

Comment: weak_ptr can be changed to shared_ptr and extend the lifetime of the object and it does not preserve the semantic of ownership of the provider.

Comment: If `allObjects` are stored as a `std::vector` you can return `std::vector<OI> const&`.

Comment: using vector<AbstractClass> is not possible.

Comment: @MeenaAlfons, good point, but how are you keeping all these objects inside the class in the first place, that can give a clue.

Comment: IMO No better way. Returning raw pointers is the correct thing to do **if** you can guarantee the owner (`Provider`) will live longer than the components that use the pointers.

Comment: @alfC inside `pimpl` in maps and vectors.

Comment: @Galik so there is no way to declare that ownership and life time semantics in code?

Comment: @MeenaAlfons In modern applications raw pointers should **never** be owning. They should *always* be considered as belonging to someone else.

Comment: @MeenaAlfons You could hide them in some kind of handle class. But they are still going to be pointers just disguised. Some people recommend using [observer_ptr](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/observer_ptr) (is that standardized yet?).

Comment: @Galik I see that modern C++ consider raw pointers as non-owning. But not everyone has those semantics because of the history of C++ and C and so on. This is why I see the need to put these semantics in code. I will look in observer_ptr.

Comment: @MeenaAlfons, in some sense this design tells you that the container of pimpl is what you can return. You can use `boost::ptr_vector` to be a bit more tidy but at the end is the same. This is the cost of runtime-polymorphism throw pointers.

Comment: `std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<ObjectInterface>>` is another option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to return references, you can use [`std::reference_wrapper`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper):

```
#include <functional>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdio>

struct A
{
    std::vector<int> objs{1, 2, 3};

    std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<int>> allObjects()
    {
        return std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<int>>(objs.begin(), objs.end());
    }
};

int main()
{
    A a;
    for (auto ref : a.allObjects())
        printf("%i\n", ref.get());
}
```